# Data Tables Move "Previous" & "Next" into the left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using the [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) with [Bootstrap](http://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) for my website. I dig into the code of the `datatables.css` but I cannot find how to move the previous and next buttons into the left.

I have tried to make it `float:left` but nothing changed.

Comment: Are you referring to the DataTables plugin? https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/

Comment: And let us see what you have tried.  Do you mean the whole pagination or the prev / next buttons only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select pagination div properly in CSS:

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
    float: left;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/385/) for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

HTML code of button

```
<div class="btns">
<span class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
<span class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</div>
```

Apply css

```
.btn.btn-primary {background: #444 none repeat scroll 0 0;border-color: #333333;}
.btn {border-radius: 3px;border-width: 0 0 3px;}
.sr-only {border: 0 none;clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px);height: 1px;margin: -1px;overflow: hidden;padding: 0;position: absolute;width: 1px;}
```